# Switch the default configuration in JBoss AS

Tags: java, configuration, jboss

I am new to JBoss Application Server. I am using version 5. I created a copy of the default dir and renamed it to say xxx and deleted all the contents of deploy folder and put just one war file. How do i tell jboss to use xxx instead of default.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you can:

1. copy any of the configurations that ship with JBoss
2. customize it
3. and then when starting the server:

> $JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh -c xxx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check out the current version, the deployment methodology of the JBoss Application Server has evolved with the release of AS7. You can [download AS7 on the JBoss site](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads), and you can read about configuration in the [Getting Started Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Getting+Started+Guide).

The documentation for AS5, including configuration, can be found [here](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/5-x/admin-and-config.html).